# Редирект страницы

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Здраствуйте!
Хотел бы спросить по поводу 301 редиректов для ссылок. Например, есть ссылка **example.com/example_page/** и если взять ссылку **example.com/example_page** или **example.com/example_page///** , то оно должно перенаправить на **example.com/example_page/**.
Подскажите, можно ли сделать такое правило для всего домена, чтобы это касалось всех его ссылок?
Спасибо

Comment: Попробуйте вот это https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35858/remove-multiple-trailing-slashes-in-a-single-301-in-htaccess

Comment: Тут надо разобраться почему вдруг не редиректит. ВП редиректит.

Comment: @SeVlad та вот в том то и проблема, что некоторые ссылки редиректит(и без слеша и с дополнтельным слешем),а некоторые нет. Не подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Не подскажу, но как минимум нужно знать какие редиректит, какие нет (чтобы проверить и разобраться). И об этом нужно написать в вопросе.